# Magento Apply only the highest category discount

Tags: php, magento

Im working on a Magento project

I have added a single product to many categories.

all those categories have their own discount rates.

for example; 
Category A - 10%, B - 20%, C - 30%, and D - 40%.

when I add the product to all these categories, 
currently customer get 100% discount. 
but I want to give only the highest discount rate of all categories
the product in that is D - 40%.

How can I do this in Magento?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that this is a Q&A site, where you post problematic code and errors and other users point the issues in your code.
Please edit your post and publish what exactly have you tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Give the price rules priorities so that the high discounts are applied first. Then configure each of them to "Stop Further Rules Processing".

BTW: The question is more suitable for [magento.stackexchange.com](https://magento.stackexchange.com/) because it is not related to programming.